# Enabling the use of a mixture of Typescript and JS in a Node Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In an existing node project written in JS we're trying to enable the use of Typescript so we can use it in our ongoing refactoring.

I've added a tsConfig like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./tsOutput",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["./"]
}
```

I've also installed the following as dev dependencies:

```
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
```

And I run tsc on build, which runs and generates a js and mapping file. I've run tried this both outputting to a separate directory and removing the outDir in the tsConfig.

To test it works, I added the following class in my test project:

```
class ExampleClass  {
    logSomeStuff(stringToLog : string, numberToLog : number, booleanToLog : boolean)
    {
        console.log(stringToLog);
        console.log(numberToLog);
        console.log(booleanToLog);
    }
}
export default ExampleClass;
```

Consume it with this JS file:

```
const { Example } = require("./Example.ts");

function TypescriptConsumerExample() {
  const blah = new Example();
  blah.logSomeStuff("String", 2, false);
}

module.exports = TypescriptConsumerExample;
```

And attempt to run this JS test:

```
const TypescriptConsumerExample = require("../TSExample/TSConsumerExample");

describe("TS test", () => {
  it("Should be able to call TS code", () => {
    TypescriptConsumerExample();
    console.log("Built");
  });
});
```

But I get this warning, which implies that it doesn't understand what TS is:

```
logSomeStuff(stringToLog : string, numberToLog : number, booleanToLog : boolean)
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

Equally, if I run the main project and try and call this TS class from index.js:

```
function TSTest()
{
    console.log("Success!");
}

export default TSTest;
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: TSTest is not a function at Object.<anonymous>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer provided by Dimava - adding the **allowJs** flag to **tsconfig.json**, it also turned out I missed changing this line in **package.json** to point to the outputs index.js file:

```
  "main": "./tsOutput/index.js",
```

In combination with the following:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node  --unhandled-rejections=warn ./tsOutput/index.js",
    "dev": "tsc && node --unhandled-rejections=warn ./tsOutput/index.js",
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `tsconfig.json` probably should have `allowJs: true` to allow js in the project at all.

Use `tsx watch --inspect src/server` for development, `tsx src/server` to launch.

[tsx](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx) allows running whatever import/require js/ts modules at once ([conpability list](https://github.com/privatenumber/ts-runtime-comparison))

---

I would recomment you to convert the *entire* project into `.ts` first (by renaming), so file extensions are consistent, in one big git commit, so blame don't break on files that were renamed and edited at once

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can go about this. You can set a script in your package.json to compile the TS and then run that compiled typescript like so:

`"scripts": { "start": "tsc && node dist/server.js" },`

Alternatively, nodemon is a super useful tool that you may already be using..and it understands typescript. You can set another script like so:

```
"dev": "npx nodemon ./src/server.ts",
```

This article by Cole Gawin goes into the details of standing up the latter https://blog.logrocket.com/configuring-nodemon-with-typescript/

Comment: Sorry - it's a bit buried in there, but I do have that in my package.json - and I can see the compiled js and mapping files.

Should that be all that is required?